# beamer and latex + dvisvgm

Tags: beamer, dvisvgm

I have the following .tex file

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame{\frametitle{Title}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item On both pages \pause 
        \item Only appears on the second page 
    \end{itemize} 
}
\end{document}
```

If I compile it with `pdflatex test.tex` I get the expected result - a pdf with two different pages. (because of `\pause`)

If, however, I compile to svg files with

```
latex test.tex
dvisvgm -n1 test.dvi --page=1-
```

I get two svg-files, but both are the same. Both look like the second page of the pdf (both: https://pastebin.com/s5hBayPB).

Can anyone explain this to me? Is it not possible to use `\documentclass{beamer}` with dvisvgm? Or is there a fix?

What I also tried is using `\documentclass[dvisvgm]{beamer}`, but then the svg contains mismatched tags and looks generally very different (https://pastebin.com/EGLZqZij).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Beamer uses PostScript operator `nulldevice` to temporarily disable all graphic output. In your case, the text of the second list item is present on both pages but disabled on the first one. dvisvgm doesn't support operator `nulldevice` yet so that the text appears anyway. I'll have a look if I can add the operator to the next release of dvisvgm.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for the explanation! I also figured out that the mismatched tags happen because of begininvisible and endinvisible moving things offscreen but not closing the tag anymore. Hmm.

Comment: @Alex You're welcome. However, I can't reproduce the mismatched tags with the recent version of dvisvgm and Beamer. It might be an issue in Beamer though because dvisvgm doesn't create isolated tags but a tree of XML nodes which always leads to correctly nested tag pairs in the output. The only exception are raw SVG fagments put in the DVI file by a LaTeX package.

Comment: Yep, those raw fragments in the svg I posted came from: /tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex `\def\pgfsys@begininvisible{\pgfsys@transformcm{1}{0}{0}{1}{2000bp}{2000bp}}` `\def\pgfsys@endinvisible{\pgfsys@transformcm{1}{0}{0}{1}{-2000bp}{-2000bp}`
I'll try updating my packages and if that doesn't help, it's not too much of a problem for me.